# Ideals and spaces defined by converging sequences

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

1.Given a set $X$ and any collection $S$ of "formal converging sequences in $X$" (a sequence $(x_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ plus a distinguished point $x$), there exists a finest topology $\tau$ which makes them genuine converging sequences; a set is in $\tau$ iff for any formal sequence whose distinguished point is in $X$, the sequence is eventually in $X$. When the collection consists of all converging sequences in a given topology this is the same as the [sequential topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Topology_of_sequentially_open_sets).

What can we say about the converging sequences in $(X,\tau)$? Clearly there may be more stuff than in $S$, since any subseqeunce (more generally subnet which is sequence) of a converging sequence converges, and if $x_i\rightarrow z$ and $y_i\rightarrow z$ then $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,...)$ also converges to $z$. There might exist converging sequence not obtainable from simple operations above. Consider the case $X=\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$. Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a prime ideal on $\mathbb{N}$; we may identify infinite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ with strictly increasing sequences. Declare that every sequence in $\mathcal{I}$ converges to $\infty$. It can be checked that every neighbourhood of $\infty$ must be cofinite, and therefore $n\rightarrow\infty$.

2.Notations as above, is there simple criterion for $(X,\tau)$ to be Hausdorff? I can see that $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$ iff $S$ does not contain sequence of form $x_i\rightarrow x$ where $x_i=y$ for infinitely many $i$ and $y\neq x$.

Comment: A topological space $X$ is Hausdorff separated if and only if the diagonal of $X \times X$ is a closed subset. Translating this into the language of convergence, a sequential topological space is Hausdorff separated if and only if convergent sequences have unique limits.

Comment: @Zhen Lin Of course but could you give a criterion in terms of properties of $S$? There must not be two sequences in $S$ with common subsequence but different distinguished points, but I cannot see if that is enough.

Comment: If there exists an unbounded but not cofinal subfamily of $(\mathbb{N},\subseteq^{*})$, which generates a proper ideal, that may serve as an example to 1.

Comment: You're asking two separate questions. Please ask them separately.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I mentioned in 2 that the first question is related to a special case of the second (at least as I understand). Do you think they are not close enough to put in a single question?

Comment: @1830rbc03: The first one should definitely be a separate question.

Comment: @n901 Thanks for your suggestion. I have posted this as a separate question.


https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3796845/ideal-on-mathbbn-with-certain-property